# Control the period for daily time series in tsibbles

Tags: time-series

I am using Rob Hyndman's `fpp3` packages and his tsibbles. I struggle to understand how to define the period of a daily time series. If I have say two years of daily data, I have the choice to define the period to be 7 or 365.25. But I don't know how to do this. Example code:

```
set.seed(3011)
day.sequence <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2019/01/01"),
                         to = as.Date("2020/12/31"), by = 1)
daily <- tibble(Day = day.sequence,
                Value = round(rnorm(length(day.sequence),
                                    mean = 100, sd = 20), 0))
daily.ts <- daily %>% 
  as_tsibble(index = Day)
```

Where do I define the proper period in the call to as_tsibble()? Or do I need to define when I fit an exponential smoothing model?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to this site! I believe this question belongs on SO but let's our former moderator and creator of this site, @rob-hyndman, decide whether this is on topic or not.

Answer (score 2):

With tsibble objects you do not need to specify the period. It will know the data are daily because of the `Day` index in this `tsibble`. Most functions will not require the period to be specified explicitly. Here is a quick modification of your example where I have included some weekly seasonality

```r
library(fpp3)

set.seed(3011)
day.sequence <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2019/01/01"),
                         to = as.Date("2020/12/31"), by = 1)
daily <- tibble(Day = day.sequence,
                Value = round(50*sin(2*pi*seq_along(day.sequence)/7) + rnorm(length(day.sequence),
                                    mean = 100, sd = 20), 0))
daily.ts <- daily %>% 
  as_tsibble(index = Day)
daily.ts %>% autoplot(Value)
```

[image]

```r
daily.ts %>% 
  model(
    ets = ETS(Value),
    arima = ARIMA(Value),
  ) 
#> # A mable: 1 x 2
#>            ets                    arima
#>        <model>                  <model>
#> 1 <ETS(A,N,A)> <ARIMA(2,0,2)(1,1,0)[7]>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As you can see, both models have picked up the weekly seasonality.

Where there are multiple types of seasonality that could be used, you can specify which one you want when modelling. For example

```r
daily.ts %>%
  model(
    stl = STL(Value ~ trend(window=Inf) + season(period=7, window='periodic'))
  ) %>%
  components() %>%
  autoplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Rob, I get it now. All clear. Greetings from cold Switzerland (remember Kandersteg?). Marcel

Comment: I have great memories of Kandersteg! Greetings from Australia.